# "Feel the heat" - is there a less slangy expression for the same concept

Tags: phrases, idiom-requests, phrase-requests

I'm writing the following sentence, and I'd like an idiomatic equivalent for "[feel the heat](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/feel_the_heat)" (to encounter an uncomfortable situation.) that would be acceptable for formal written English:

> Warily eyeing the enemy army's advance, the old king began _______

Comment: It depends on exactly what you're trying to say. For example, was the king actually *scared*, or was he feeling energised and confident as the tension rose in those around him?

Comment: I would say he was getting scared. I imagine beads of sweat forming on his forehead...

Comment: '...the old king really began to feel the pressure.' Strange how a slightly different metaphor can alter the register.

Comment: I'd probably ditch continuous in favour of an infinitive form - *began **to feel nervous,*** or more metaphorically, perhaps,  *began **to sweat***. But it's just writing advice.

Comment: Could you use your own "the old king started to feel *beads of sweat forming on his forehead*"? Then you would not need 'Warily' at all.

Comment: There are many phrases one could use, such as *feeling the pressure*, *sensing the pressure*, *to worry*, *feeling apprehensive*... or consider: *the old king began to sweat.*

Comment: @EdwinAshworth why not add the answer?

Comment: @PV22 I don't see it as being sufficiently different from the original to warrant one.

Answer (score 2):

Warily eyeing the enemy army's advance, the old king became **apprehensive**
(of any undesirable outcome).

> apprehensive
>
> adjective:
>
> 1. anxious or fearful that something bad or unpleasant will happen.
>
> "The king was apprehensive that the enemy will capture the city and dethrone him"

Answer (score -3):

"It was **squeaky bum time** for the king"

From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/squeaky_bum_time)

> (noun, uncountable) (informal, chiefly Britain)
> An exciting part of a sporting event, particularly the final moments of a close game or season.
>
> Attributed to Sir Alex Ferguson, famed Scottish association football manager and former player referencing the sound made by moving around in a plastic seat while squirming under pressure.